# django custom filter for urldecode giving maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: django, urldecode

i want to write a urldecode template filter and i have a template tag folder under my app with the following code :

```
from django import template
from urllib import unquote

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def unquote(value):
    return unquote(value)

class SetVarNode(template.Node):

    def __init__(self, var_name, var_value):
        self.var_name = var_name
        self.var_value = var_value

    def render(self, context):
        try:
            value = template.Variable(self.var_value).resolve(context)
        except template.VariableDoesNotExist:
            value = ""
        context[self.var_name] = value
        return u""

@register.tag(name='set')
def set_var(parser, token):
    """
        {% set <var_name>  = <var_value> %}
    """
    parts = token.split_contents()
    if len(parts) < 4:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("'set' tag must be of the form:  {% set <var_name>  = <var_value> %}")
    return SetVarNode(parts[1], parts[3])
```

then i am calling my registed filter in my template like this :

> kmz.file|unquote

Any ideas why?

Comment: Why what? Anyway, you should rename your filter to `unquote_filter`, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you import unquote and then redefine it.

Use this instead:

```
from urllib import unquote as unquote_old

@register.filter
def unquote(value):
    return unquote_old(value)
```

or

```
from urllib import unquote

@register.filter
def unquote_new(value):
    return unquote(value)
```